# Get table name from a PGTable

Tags: typescript, postgresql, drizzle

I am starting out a new project with Drizzle ORM. Starting out with some assumptions:

- The primary keys on all the tables in my database will be uniformly uniformly typed and they will all be called `id`.
- All the foreign keys will be in the form of `table_name_id` in the database and the model property will always be `tableNameId`.

Since I can make these assumptions, I thought I could significantly reduce the amount of boilerplate required for specifying foreign keys:

```
import {
  type PgColumn,
  type PgTableWithColumns,
  pgTableCreator,
  serial,
} from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

import { camelCase, snakeCase } from "lodash";

export const pgTable = pgTableCreator((name) => {
  return `some-app_${name}`;
});

export function id() {
  return serial("id").primaryKey();
}

type TableWithId = PgTableWithColumns<{
  name: string;
  schema: string | undefined;
  dialect: "pg";
  columns: {
    id: PgColumn;
  };
}>;

export function fk(...relations: (TableWithId | TableWithId[])[]) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    relations.flatMap((entry) => {
      const isOptional = Array.isArray(entry);
      const tables = isOptional ? entry : [entry];

      return tables.map((table) => {
        const columnName = `${snakeCase(`)}_id`;
        const propertyName = `${camelCase(table._.name)}Id`;
        const column = bigint(columnName, { mode: "number" }).references(() => {
          return table.id;
        });

        return [propertyName, isOptional ? column : column.notNull()];
      });
    }),
  );
}
```

This code is intended to be used as such:

```
export const contact = pgTable("contacts", {
  id: id(),
  firstName: varchar("first_name", { length: 128 }).notNull(),
  lastName: varchar("last_name", { length: 128 }).notNull(),
  ...fk(phone, [email], [address]),
  ...timestamps(),
});
```

Here a relation to the phone and email tables are mandatory (not null), but the relation to the email and address are optional.

The issue arises with accessing the name for a given `PgTable`. When I inspect the type of `contact` in my editor I see that they are type hinted with `PgTableWithColumns`. Which is what I used in the type hint to the `fk` function.

As a result as far as Typescript is concerned the function is correct. However when I run the code, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

This is referring to the expression: `table._.name`. When I log out table, I see that it does not match the type. The underscore property is infact missing, but the name provided to the table is present in a symbol key `Symbol(drizzle:BaseName)`.

However, I am not sure how to access this property as I have not been able to import the symbol from anywhere.

It seems like the types for this package are broken and I might end up filing a bug with drizzle. But I kind of want to get this to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

How about `getTableName`?

```
import { getTableName } from "drizzle-orm";
const tableName = getTableName(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me

```js
import { ExtractTablesWithRelations } from "drizzle-orm";
import * as schema from './schema.ts'

export type RawTableNames = keyof ExtractTablesWithRelations<typeof schema>;
```

Where `schema` is the same object passed to your drizzle db init.